# Bringing an open file to the fore window with vba code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using vba code to open an access database from another access database using the following codes

```
Public Declare Function ShellExecuteA Lib "shell32.dll" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal strOperation As String, _
ByVal strFile As String, ByVal strParameters As String, ByVal strDirectory As _
String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long


Dim lngreturn As Long 
lngreturn = ShellExecuteA(GetDesktopWindow(), "OPEN", strFilePath, "", "", vbNormalFocus)
```

It works fine except that it keeps opening new instances of the database even if there is one already open in the background. I need codes to bring the opened database to the foreground. NB:- I have used AppActivate and it does not work because I am already in msaccess and the other database that I want to bring to the foreground is also in access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an **Application title** for the second database in File - Options - Current database.

Then use that title with `AppActivate`.

Alternatively, instead of using `ShellExecuteA`, build a full command line (including the path to msaccess.exe), and use the [`Shell()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63) function to start the second database:

> Runs an executable program and returns a Variant (Double) representing the program's task ID if successful

Store this task ID in a public or static variable, and use it with `AppActivate`.

Comment: Setting the Application Title in Current database option dialog works well